# TextWatch no actualiza como deberia

Tags: android, textview, edittext

Buenas, estoy intentando hacer un textview dinamico, uno que reciba datos de una base de datos, el otro que muestre el resultado de la operacion del primer textview menos lo que se esta ingresando por el edittext, sin embargo no logro hacer que se muestre como deberia.

Aqui esta el código:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pago_correo);
        saldoUsrAct = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.saldoact);
        saldototal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.STotal);
        monto = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.transmonto);
        correodest = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.transcorreo);
        concepto = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.transconcepto);
        aceptar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_enviar);
        cancelar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_cancelar);




        saldito = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                saldototal.setText(addNumbers());
            }
        };



        saldototal.addTextChangedListener(saldito);


    }

    private String addNumbers() {
        int number1;
        int number2;
        if(saldoUsrAct.getText().toString() != "" && saldoUsrAct.getText().length() > 0) {
            number1 = Integer.parseInt(saldoUsrAct.getText().toString());
        } else {
            number1 = 0;
        }
        if(monto.getText().toString() != "" && monto.getText().length() > 0) {
            number2 = Integer.parseInt(monto.getText().toString());
        } else {
            number2 = 0;
        }

        return Integer.toString(number1 - number2);
    }

}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Que es lo que te falla? Pudieras dar mas detalles?

Comment: Lo que falta es que funcione, por que no realiza el cambio del textview. La idea es que en un textview se muestren los resultados a medida que se ingresan los datos en el edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

veo que estas colocando esta linea de código:

```
saldototal.addTextChangedListener(saldito);
```

Siendo "saldototal" de tipo TextView...
intenta colocar el TextWatcher al EditText correspondiente

Comment: Efectivamente, me ha funcionado con la observación que diste y en las pruebas funciona bien.

Ahora bien, el problema que estoy teniendo es que yo traigo una cadena desde un jason que viene formateada de la siguiente forma:

###.###,##

El script no me reconoce los decimales, y es probable que existan decimales con los cuales deba trabajar, de que forma puedo usar la cadena que recibo y hacer las operaciones matematicas necesarias?

Comment: Si deseas pasar tu string del formato ###.###,## a un double prueba con:
           

`double ad = Double.parseDouble( str.replaceAll(".", "").replace(",", ".") ); `

Suponiendo que la coma es separador de decimales y punto es separador de miles ...

Answer (score 0):

Puede que el problema sea que estas cambiando el texto de saldototal, y al terminar la operación y hacer saldototal.setText() se vuelve a cambiar y vuelve a realizar la operación y así sucesivamente. Creo que deberias usar otro edit text para alojar el resultado de la operación. 
De todas formas no explicas el problema, solo dices que no anda, pero el problema es que no muestra el resultado? muestra resultado erroneo? se clava la app?

Comment: Al principio se me crashaba la app, con este codigo no se me traba, pero tampoco se ejecuta como deberia. La idea es que cuando se le coloque un valor en el edittext de forma automatica el textview2 tomaindo los valores del textview1 y del edittext

Comment: se entiende lo que te digo? se puede clavar la app, porque haces los cambios en el mismo TextView saldototal. Al ponerle un textwahcher a saldototal, este ejecuta la operación cuando hay un cambio en saldototal, y eso puede entrar en un bucle infinito. Por lo que explicas, el textwacher deberia estar sobre el editext, no sobre el TextView. 
Para mi deberias aplicar el textwacher sobre monto. De manera que cuando monto cambie, se muestre el resultado de la operación